# Is there a way to limit users signing up to my Android App?

Tags: android, flutter

I am developing an Android app for a client, and I want to restrict the app to a limited number of users, e.g. 50. I want to publish the app in the Play Store, so I will be able to update the app when necessary, and this user limitation will prevent additional users from using the app even if they download it from the Play Store.

Is there any way to automatically limit users through either Play Store licensing, or Firebase Authentication, or am I supposed to manual set up a licensing/verification platform (I do not know if I am correct)? I am a new developer and I would like to find an easy and effective solution for this. I am using Flutter to develop my app.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Authentication > Sign Up Method

Firebase has a quota per hour but we need to research if we can put a quota on the whole time.

I suggest you check it yourself. If you have 50 uses, you cannot become a member.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will take a look at it